# Automatically add date to .gif

Tags: scripting, cron, gif, gimp

Alright,

What Im looking for is a script that would automatically add a date to a .gif, which I can run daily as a cron job. I don't know perl very well, but It seems that Perl & Gimp might be a way to get the job done. Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can create such a script

thanks!

Comment: By "add a date" do you mean add something to the image data so that when viewed in an image browser the user sees a date overlaid on some portion of the image (i.e. like some cameras can imprint on the negative?)

Comment: What do you mean by "add a date"? To the file name, or meta file information, or do you want to insert a date text overtop the image?

Comment: By add date, I actually mean adding today's date automatically as text in a designated area for the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is php with the gd extension.  Have a look at the manual pages for imagestring [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php) and imagegif [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php).

Answer (score 2):

I once implemented something similar using just a shell script and the [`-draw` option](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#draw) to [ImageMagick's convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) program.

For a slightly more advanced approach, I'd use Python and [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), which should be a lot easier to work with than trying to script the Gimp.